# iOS SecKeyEncrypt OAEP SHA512

Tags: ios, encryption, hash, rsa

From what I can tell looking through the various padding values for the SecKeyEncrypt method in Apple's security framework, it does not support OAEP padding with a SHA512 hash digest. In fact, I can't seem to determine if the SecKeyEncrypt method does any sort of hashing/masking of each block during the CBC process.

Herein lies my problem. All my other platforms (PHP, Android, .NET) use RSA with OAEP padding and a SHA512 digest.

For example: In C# we can use BouncyCastle's [OaepEncoding](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp/blob/master/crypto/src/crypto/encodings/OaepEncoding.cs) class which accepts any Digest and performs the hash/mask operation during the block cipher encryption process. In php, the [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) project provides the same functionality.

And finally, my question... can this same functionality be achieved on iOS by somehow using a hybrid of "manual" hashing and using SecKeyEncrypt? Or am I missing something much more obvious here.

Cheers!

EDIT: I think I could probably hash/mask each block by porting the bouncy castle code and then pass the new byte array to SecKeyEncrypt for encrpytion, but that begs the question, does SecKeyEncrypt do that already using some other hashing algo internally?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It appears this is not possible native to the Security framework for iOS. I have had a ton of issues getting OAEP RSA encryption to work properly cross platform.

However, I did just hear from a third party library provider, Chillkat, that they are adding support for this. See: http://www.chilkatforum.com/questions/7778/ios-rsa-encryption-using-oaep-sha512

EDIT: I installed Chilkat's library and had it working in minutes.

Comment: Submit a bug report, Apple needs to know what dev need: bugreporter.apple.com

Comment: @Zaph haha.. just tried and it won't let me log in (yes, it is the right uname and pass) - no error, just doesn't redirect properly. How do I submit a bug report for their bug reporting system ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 10.0, the `.rsaEncryptionOAEPSHA512` option has been [added](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/kseckeyalgorithmrsaencryptionoaepsha512?language=objc) as a `SecKeyAlgorithm`.

**Swift 4**

```swift
let attributes: [String: Any] = [ ... ]
let pk = SecKeyCreateRandom(attributes as CFDictionary, nil)!
let pub = SecKeyCopyPublicKey(pk)!
let message = "Encrypt me".data(using: .utf8)!

var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
let cipherText = SecKeyCreateEncryptedData(pub, .rsaEncryptionOAEPSHA512, message as CFData, &error)
```